# File navigation in Gvim

Tags: file, vim, navigation, shortcut

In Gvim is there any way to trace back a series of files opened using "gf"

```
File1 <gf> opens  File2 <gf> opens File3 <gf> opens File4 ...
```

I would like someway to go back to File1. Like Ctrl+6 except for the it toggles between last two files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map a keystroke to execute `:bp`

```
nmap <keystroke> :bp<CR>
```

See `:h :map` for more information.

Comment: I tried nmap fg :bp
It works but need to hit enter after fg. Is there anyway to add an enter after fg ?

Comment: Didn't you see the `<CR>` at the end? That's because it was missing, sorry. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Like answered by [freitass](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89112/freitass), a solution would be inserting following line in .gvimrc

```
nmap fg :bp<CR>
```

gf would navigate forward
fg would navigate backward

Comment: What then if you want to move your cursor from the current position to the next occurrence of the letter 'g' on the same line? [`:help f`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#f).

Comment: I suggest a read in [:h jumps](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#:jumps) and [vim buffer FAQ](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_buffer_FAQ)